# Почему компонент vue-phone-number-input ломает разметку?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Простое SPA vue.js с использованием vuetify. На одном из представлений выводиться информация о мероприятии и форма регистрации. Форма, поля ввода, кнопка из vuetify. На форме также reCAPTCHA.
Разметка в порядке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после отправки данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для удобства ввода телефонного номера добавил на форму компонент vue-phone-number-input. После добавления разметка сломалась.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Клонировал vue-phone-number-input, посмотрел стили. Все стили в компонентах scoped. Не пойму в чем проблема! Подскажите, пжлст, в чем может быть проблема и как исправить!

Comment: Не по теме, но прочитайте про "[тся](http://tsya.ru)" в русском языке — у Вас ошибки и на скриншотах, и в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Обратился к автору компонента. Описал ситуацию и выложил на гитхабе проект. Через день автор отписался. Он внес корректировки и предложил использовать новую версию компонента. Теперь разметка не ломается. Кому интересно -…версия компонента 1.0.4